# search matching keyword on typing anything

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, ajax

Iam new to programming.

Please dont mind if its a simple question.

I have a search box,

**html**

```
<input type="text" id="search" placeholder="Search" autocomplete="off"/>
```

When i type anything in search box, for example like abc, I need to show in dropdown as , restaurents matching 'abc', this is to be done in frontend.

Here is the code i have written to get data,

**js**

```
$("#search").keyup(function(){
    if ($(this).val().length == 3) {
        console.log($(this).closest(".row-fluid").find("ul").attr('id'));
        $(this).closest(".row-fluid").find("ul").css('display', 'none');
    }
}).autocomplete({
    source: function(request, response) {
        $.ajax({
            type: "POST",
            url: "/search/site_search/"+$('#search').val(),
            dataType: "json",
            success: function(data) {
            response( $.map( data.result, function( item ) {
                return {
                    label: item.complaint_title,
                    value: item.complaint_iid,
                };
            }));
        },
        error: function(result) {
            alert("Error");
        }
        });
    },
    select: function (event, ui) {
        console.log(ui.item);
    },
    focus: function( event, ui ) {
        $( "#search" ).val( ui.item.label );
        return false;
    }
}).data( "ui-autocomplete" )._renderItem = function( ul, item ) {
    return $( "<li>" )
        .data( "ui-autocomplete-item", item )
        .append( "<a>" + item.label + "</a>" )
        .appendTo( ul );
};
```

Can anyone tell me how to do this.

Comment: You need to *ask a question*. What is wrong? You have code that *appears* to give an autocomplete. Please help *us* help *you*. `:)`

Comment: Nothing wrong in my code as of now. Now if i type anything in search box like abc, in dropdown i need to show the message suppose, restaurents matching 'abc'. Iam not getting how to do it?

Comment: When the autocomplete box is open, right-click and `Inspect Element`. See what the parent element is and it's first child (probably a `ul` or `div`). Create a `$('<div>')` or `$('<span>')` with your text in it and use `$.before()` after selecting for the first child. This will insert a node with your text at the beginning of the autocomplete box. Of course, you would do this during the `success` handler.

Comment: can you please make it clear with some example code.

Comment: I think you should to do it first. You don't improve if you don't stretch yourself. There are also many examples of inserting DOM nodes using jQuery, not the least of which is the jQuery docs page for `$.before()`.